Replace a string in a script without modifying the file, and then to execute it
I have both BSD (default) and GNU Awk implementations installed on a Mac (the latter is envoked using gawk instead of just awk), and I have a shell script with contents like this:
awk -v maxLen=72 '
    .
    .
    .
' "$1" > "$2"

Now the tricky part. To work correctly, the script must use GNU Awk. Which means I have at least two options: 1)To modify the first line of the script so that there will be gawk instead of awk, 2) To make a system-wide alias for GNU Awk so that it will be envoked using awk instead gawk. But I would prefer to avoid either option, and instead to execute the script using a wrapper. That is, instead of
./script.sh input.txt output.txt

I would prefer something like
sed -e 's/awk/gawk/' script.sh

and then to pass the output to Zsh somehow. I was told this is possible using Zsh process substitution feature, but how?

Why the .sh extension if those are zsh scripts?

@StéphaneChazelas, I can't answer for the OP, but I personally use the .sh filename suffix on any private shell script, regardless of what shell they're written for. It's more a "namespace" (to not inadvertently clash with existing tools) than meta-data saying "this is a particular type of shell script".  I agree with people who say executables, in general, don't need a filename suffix, but if we add one, I don't think it needs to reflect the particular variant of shell language used.  But, shrug.

@StéphaneChazelas On macOS this is convenient for me, because if I select a file and press the Space bar key, and if the file has a "supported" filename extension, macOS opens a quick-look preview. If the filename extension is not supported, or if there is no filename extension, this doesn't work.

Sorry, I misread your question. I thought you ask why use filename extensions whereas shell scripts are often don't have ones. I agree that using .zsh instead of .sh makes sense. Thanks for pointing this out.

You can do:
sed 's/awk/gawk/g' script.sh | zsh -s input output

Or:
zsh -- <(sed 's/awk/gawk/g' script.sh) input output

Beware it will also turn echo The hawk squawked | /usr/bin/awk 1 into echo The hgawk squgawked | /usr/bin/gawk 1.
Instead, using zsh's multios feature, you could do:
zsh -s <<< 'awk() { gawk "$@"; }' < script.sh input output

Or you could use perl instead of awk which can do anything any awk implementation can do and a lot more, and for which there's only one implementation (several versions thereof of course, but the API is relatively stable and generally backward compatible between versions).

Assuming GNU awk was installed using Homebrew on macOS, the gawk package displays the following at the end of installation (see brew info gawk if you missed it):
GNU "awk" has been installed as "gawk".
If you need to use it as "awk", you can add a "gnubin" directory
to your PATH from your ~/.bashrc and/or ~/.zshrc like:

    PATH="/opt/homebrew/opt/gawk/libexec/gnubin:$PATH"

Let the script do that modification of PATH before running your awk command:
#!/bin/sh

PATH=/opt/homebrew/opt/gawk/libexec/gnubin:$PATH

awk ...

The awk command will be searched for in $PATH, and with the modified path the executable will be found in /opt/homebrew/opt/gawk/libexec/gnubin, if that path exists. On systems where that path will not exist, it will use whatever other command it can find called awk.
Instead of the awk command in the above script, you could use exec "$@", which would make the script a wrapper as you suggest:
./gnu-awk-path-fixing-wrapper ./my-awk-calling-script other arguments here

Note that on some macOS systems, Homebrew uses /usr/local/homebrew instead of /opt/homebrew.  If your Homebrew installation is done correctly, you should be able to use $HOMEBREW_PREFIX for that part of the path.
Note too that this silently would use a non-GNU awk if GNU awk was not installed on the system. To counter that, either test for the existence of gawk in your path before running your awk command in your script (with command -v gawk), or simply use the gawk command instead of awk.

To protect against whutespace injection: PATH=...:"$PATH"

@pts I'm not quite sure what you mean. The shell would not split the value of $PATH in an assignment.  There is no need to quote the variable expansion (but you can if you want, obviously). See e.g. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/68694/when-is-double-quoting-necessary?noredirect=1&lq=1
